# HTML, Javascript loop end before the visiting last element in the array

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am a beginner in web developing.
I am trying to create something with code similar to the code that I attached below.
However the function in the script end before running through the array.
can anybody help me with it?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_58>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_59>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_60>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_61>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_61>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_63>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_64>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_65>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_66>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_67>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_68>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_69>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_70>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_71>
    <input type=checkbox id=verify_72>
    <button onclick="verifyall('68~70~71~72~69~58~59~60~61~62~63~64~65~66~67')">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function verifyall(attid) {
        var lstattid=attid.split("~");
        var count = lstattid.length;
        for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
          alert(i+" of "+count);
          var vname = "verify_" + lstattid[i];
          if(document.getElementById(vname).disabled == false){

          }
        }   
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it run through the array at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code crashes when it gets to the ninth element of the array. Your list of ID numbers has the value `62` in it, but there is no checkbox with the ID `verify_62`, so this line:

```
if(document.getElementById(vname).disabled == false){
```

Fails with the following error:

```
Unable to get property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference
```

If you look in the console, you will see this.

Answer (score 0):

your script throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of null` because, if you look through your checkbox list you will see there are 2 items having same IDs `verify_61`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 61 duplicated, so its trying to look for 62.

its easier to get them if you put a name on them like "verify" and use document.getElementByName('verify').. that should give you an array of all the things you want to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to access property 'disabled' of element with `id:'verify_62'`, which is not present in DOM.

So, `document.getElementById('verify_62')` returns `'null'`. And 'null' do not have property 'disabled'.

So, do not pass `'62'` in argument, or add checkbox with `id 'verify_62'` in your HTML.